# Why are there two spring-data-cassandra github projects?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm considering using Spring Data Cassandra in a project.

I see TWO projects on Github for spring-data-cassandra.

Why?  Which is the official version?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra
This is the one linked to from http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

https://github.com/SpringData/spring-data-cassandra
Is this just somebody's fork of the official version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official project is located at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra.

The other project is administered by Alex Shvid, who contributed to the official project initially but is no longer involved.